# Конвертер Валют вместе с Volley

Tags: android

Проблема такая: Есть желание интереса ради сделать конвертер валют через парсинг с API. Задумка такая,она конечно не совсем разумная, но другого ничего придумать не могу. При вводе в EditText цифр, должна происходить операция деления .То есть
X = Z/Y.  Z это число,которое я ввожу. Y - это курс какой-то валюты при базовой в доллар, к примеру. X соответственно результат. Но при попытке сконвертировать EditText в int или double, то приходит вот это :
**"android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference"**

Не хватает опыта,чтобы понять дальнейшие действия.
И как правильно получить цифры в данной ситуации, не понимаю абсолютно. Подскажите пожалуйста хоть какой-то выход из данной ситуации. Вот мой что-то похожее на код:

```
public class MainUsd extends AppCompatActivity   {

 private RecyclerView recyclerView;
 private Adapter myAdapter;

 private ArrayList<CurrencyItems>mListCur;
 private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
 private  TextView valueCurrency;
 private TextView result;
 private EditText usdText;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recylcer);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mListCur = new ArrayList<>();
    valueCurrency = findViewById(R.id.currency_equally);
    result = findViewById(R.id.result);
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    parseJSON();

 EditText usdTexter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mount_number);
 int value = Integer.parseInt(usdText.getText().toString());}

 private void  parseJSON() {

        String url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=EUR,GBP,JPY,USD";
        final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new
                Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonArray = response.getJSONObject("rates");

                            double addEUR = jsonArray.getDouble("EUR");
                            double addGBP = jsonArray.getDouble("GBP");
                            double addJPY = jsonArray.getDouble("JPY");
                            double addUSD = jsonArray.getDouble("USD");

                            mListCur.add(new CurrencyItems(" " , addEUR, " "));
                            mListCur.add(new CurrencyItems("", addUSD, " "));
                            mListCur.add(new CurrencyItems("", addEUR, " "));
                            myAdapter = new Adapter(MainUsd.this, mListCur);

                            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainUsd.this, "Check your internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mRequestQueue.add(request);  }}
```

CurrencyItems.java

```
public class CurrencyItems {


private int imageAbb;
private String abbCuerrency;
private String currencyName;
private String currecnyEmblem;
private String mountNumber;
private double rates;


private String result;

public CurrencyItems(String amount, Double rate, String results){
    mountNumber = amount;
    rates = rate;
    result = results;
}




    public int getImageAbb() { return imageAbb; }
public String getAbbCuerrency() { return abbCuerrency; }
public String getCurrencyName() { return currencyName; }
public String getCurrecnyEmblem() { return currecnyEmblem; }
public String getMountNumber() { return mountNumber; }
public Double getRates() { return rates; }
public String getResult() { return result; }}
```

Comment: проверьте, чтобы этот EditText был с идентификатором R.id.mount_number в XML разметке

Comment: К сожалению, проверял уже много раз. И по другому даже писал. Результат тот же.

Comment: Я так и не смог найти где у вас "usdTexter" используется. Инициализируется да, используется нет. Что у вас тогда может крешиться?

Comment: покажите XML - разметку